# Michael Hartl's Tutorial Chapter 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on MH's tutorial and I keep getting these three errors. It's saying that there 'submit' is an undefined variable and I don't see why. Not sure what the problem is. Any suggestions

```
Failures:

  1) User pages after saving the user 
     Failure/Error: before { click_button submit }
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `submit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_4:0x007f8e816f7c70>
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:50:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User pages after saving the user 
     Failure/Error: before { click_button submit }
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `submit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_4:0x007f8e841d4740>
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:50:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) User pages after saving the user 
     Failure/Error: before { click_button submit }
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `submit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_4:0x007f8e84265d80>
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:50:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00577 seconds
3 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:53 # User pages after saving the user 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:55 # User pages after saving the user 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:54 # User pages after saving the user
```

This is the user_pages_spec file

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

    subject { page }

    describe "profile page" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

        before { visit user_path(user) }

        it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
    end

    describe "signup page" do
        before { visit signup_path }

        it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
        it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
    end

    describe "signup" do

        before { visit signup_path }

        let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

        describe "with invalid information" do
          it "should not create a user" do
            expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
          end
        end

        describe "with valid information" do
            before do
                fill_in "Name",          with: "Example User"
                fill_in "Email",         with: "user@example.com"
                fill_in "Password",      with: "foobar"
                fill_in "Confirmation",  with: "foobar"
            end

            it "should create a user" do
                expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
            end
        end
    end

    describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button submit }
        let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
        it { should have_link('Sign out') }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your formatting quick in the spec, take a look now and it should be more obvious why...

You have `let(:submit) { "Create my account" }` defined in the `signup` context, but you're trying to use it outside, in the `after saving the user` context.  You need to move it out so both can see it, or re-define it within the other context.

To be honest that part of your spec kind of doesn't make sense, what are you submitting?

Answer (score 0):

To test **after saving user** block you should do this when creating user succeed this means **inside** `with valid information` context, so you must just nest your context `after saving user` inside the `describe "with valid information" do` which is in the `"sign up"` context, and you have already **let(:submit)** declaration which create your submit variable.

Your code will looks like this :

```
describe "sign up" do 

  before { visit signup_path } 

  let(:submit) { "Create my account" } 
  .
  .
  .
  .

  describe "with valid information" do

    # here you fill fields for signing up a new user
    .
    .
    .
    describe "after saving the user" do
      # when you are here, you have already filling fields of signup form, so you should submit these fields and the code below let you do this
      before { click_button submit }
      let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
      it { should have_link('Sign out') }
    end
  end
end
```

conclusion : just move `after saving the user` block before the `end` of `sign up` block